# Why is the SQL dump file size so small compared to original db size?

Tags: database, postgresql

I used pg_dump to backup a database, the result sql file is less than 2 MB.
I looked up the size of the original database, it is over 30 MB, I thought something went wrong, so I execute the sql to restore the database elsewhere, and it turns out the backup is actually OK.

AFAIK, when generating the backup SQL file, a lot of extra text like `'INSERT INTO ...'` should make the SQL file larger than original data.

What did I miss here?

Comment: Indexes are not included in the dump, I would imagine

Comment: Indexes, metadata, possible updates cause old versions to stay until they're vacuumed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends very much on your database schema. When you do some serious indexing, these indexes will occupy by far the most space. They are not backed up. Of course, your primary key columns are already automatically indexed.

Answer (score 1):

There are several backup formats for postgres. One is plain format (`CREATE` and `COPY` statements in text file). Other formats use compact binary data representation with configurable compression.

Check your db dump format. It is normal to have small dump size for binary dump formats.

You can find details about all dump formats here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html